# DKIM - email passing through multiple services

Tags: exchange-server, dkim

If an email went from my helpdesk system (which has DKIM) to our exchange server to relay (which has DKIM) to our spam filter (which has DKIM) - will anything break?

Which DKIM record record will be used by the receiving party?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with "has DKIM". The question is where the email is being signed with the DKIM secret key, and if the public key is publicly available to the recipient.

Comment: Our helpdesk system is asking us to sign emails with a secret key & publish a public key

Our exchange server has the functionality to sign email with a private key & wants us to publish a public key.

Our spam filter wants us to sign emails as they pass through & publish a key.

If all 3 options have signing capabilities & an email was routed through all 3 (origin:  helpdesk, then sent to the exchange server as the helpdesk is using one of its email addresses, then it passes through the spam filter to leave our network.) Will the email be signed 3 times Or is it only signed at origin?

Comment: With 3 different dkim selectors every server can individual sign the email. The different public keys must be available to everyone. it could be that the exchange server and the spam filter does not resent the email but just route it as is so no signing occurs. It could also be that all systems share the same secret dkim key. Look into DKIM selectors